# What is the meaning of "cross" in the following example?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

Huawei's copy for their new smartwatch:

*"Fashion, never stops.
Pushing boundaries through technology.
To **cross**, to sport, to explore".*

What is meant by "cross" in this example?

Comment: What country did you see this in? It really looks like they never checked it with an English native. It's almost word salad.

Comment: What @DoneWithThis. said. The text is garbage right from that invalid comma after the first word.

Comment: i'm not sure of our stance on the word ['chinglish'](https://ltl-school.com/chinglish/) but that's what this appears to be.

Answer (score 5):

The implication is "cross the boundaries", from the previous sentence. But beware, this is marketing speak and not a good model for learning English. It is basically meaningless drivel, at best. I'm more intrigued by what they intend "sport" to mean in this context. The only grammatically correct meaning I can see is in the sense of "wear". But, again, you should not expect any coherent meaning from marketing copy.

Comment: 1,000 kudos for "coherent meaning from marketing copy." God bless the writer who got paid for writing copy in a language not known well, but stringing together dictionary words that sounded good in the original.

Comment: kudos has no singular form. It is not, in fact, a plural at all. You cannot have more than one 'kudo', like you cannot have one 'applau' :P

Comment: My guess that 'sport' was intended to mean show off, to wear in a showy way.

Comment: @WeatherVane - having spent the best part of a decade in Japan… I really wouldn't bet on that. My first guess would be 'to play sports', but $deity knows what 'to cross' was meant to be.